# Elements not centering, Justify not working

Tags: css

The features section of this project just wont center the photos for some reason. Justify content and justify items seems to have no effect. The more I zoom in the more off center the images with the camera parts get. This is the #features-section, midway in my css. I have included a screenshot, see link at the bottom of code, as it won't let me embed it yet. Thanks!

```css
/* Universal Styles */

html {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.main-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 5.3125rem;
  /* To offset for fixed header. */
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #4a4a4a;
  color: white;
}

.image-container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image-container img {
  display: block;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  .main-content {
    top: 2.5625rem;
  }
}


/* Header */

header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #c6c1c1;
  background-color: white;
}

header .content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1.875rem;
}

header .logo {
  flex: 1;
}

header nav ul {
  display: flex;
}

nav li {
  padding-left: 3.5rem;
}

nav a {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #4a4a4a;
}

header .icon {
  width: 1rem;
  padding-left: .75rem;
}

header .mobile {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  header .desktop {
    display: none;
  }
  header .mobile {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  header .content {
    padding: .5rem 0;
  }
  header .mobile ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
  header .mobile li {
    padding: 0;
  }
  header .mobile .button {
    padding: .1875rem .5rem;
    background-color: #9dc20b;
    line-height: 1.6;
    color: white;
  }
}


/* Sign Up Section */

#sign-up-section {
  background-image: url("../images/banner-landingpage.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: 43.5rem;
}

#sign-up-cta {
  margin-top: 170px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 170px;
  padding: 0 5rem 2.5rem 5rem;
  border: solid 1px #979797;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #9dc20b;
}

#sign-up-cta .content {
  width: 25.625rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: 1.4;
  color: white;
}

#sign-up-cta h1 {
  font-size: 3.125rem;
}

#sign-up-cta h2 {
  font-size: 2.25rem;
}

#sign-up-cta span strong {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#sign-up-cta .cursive {
  font-family: "Damion", cursive;
}

#sign-up-cta .striking {
  font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif;
  padding-bottom: .75rem;
}

#sign-up-cta .button {
  margin-top: 1.625rem;
  padding: 1.25rem 7.25rem;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  #sign-up-section {
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 28rem;
  }
  #sign-up-cta {
    position: static;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
  }
  #sign-up-cta .content {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  #sign-up-cta .email {
    display: none;
  }
  #sign-up-cta h1 {
    font-size: 3.125rem;
  }
  #sign-up-cta h2 {
    font-size: 2.25rem;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 450px) {
  #sign-up-section {
    height: 20rem;
  }
  #sign-up-cta h1 {
    font-size: 2.25rem;
  }
  #sign-up-cta h2 {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
}


/* Features Section */

#features-section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 4rem 5%;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  border: #9dc20b solid 5px;
}

.feature {
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 2rem;
  margin: 0px 1.25rem;
  background-color: white;
  width: 40rem;
}

.feature .image-container {
  border: #9dc20b solid 5px;
  width: 90%;
  height: 65%;
  margin: 2rem 2rem 2.5rem 2rem;
}

.feature .image-container img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.feature h2 {
  padding-bottom: .5rem;
  font-size: 2.25rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #4a4a4a;
}

.feature h3 {
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #4a4a4a;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 890px) {
  .feature h2 {
    font-size: 1.125rem;
    line-height: 1.3;
    font-weight: normal;
  }
  .feature h3 {
    font-size: .875rem;
    line-height: 1.4;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  #features-section {
    flex-flow: column;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .feature {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1.25rem 1rem 0 1rem;
  }
}


/* Filters Section */

#filters-section {
  padding: 4rem 0;
  background-color: #4a4a4a;
}

#filters-section .content {
  padding: 0 .625rem;
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
}

#filters-section .content h2 {
  font-size: 2.25rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}

#filters-section .content h3 {
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.4;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: white;
}

#filters-section .images-container {
  display: flex;
  /*max-width: 100%;*/
  padding: 0 1%;
  justify-content: center;
}

#filters-section .images-container .image-container img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  #filters-section {
    padding: 1.5rem 0 0 0;
  }
  #filters-section .content {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
  }
  #filters-section .content h2 {
    padding-bottom: .625rem;
    font-size: 1.125rem;
    line-height: 1.3;
    font-weight: normal;
  }
  #filters-section .content h3 {
    font-size: .875rem;
    line-height: 1.4;
  }
  #filters-section .images-container {
    padding: 0;
  }
  #filters-section .extra {
    display: none;
  }
}


/* Quotes Section */

#quotes-section {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  padding-top: 5rem;
  padding-bottom: 5rem;
  justify-content: center;
}

.quotes-section content {}

#quotes-section .quote {
  padding-right: 1.875rem;
  font-family: "Palatino", serif;
  font-size: 1.875rem;
  line-height: 1.1;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #4a4a4a;
}


/* #quotes-section .quote-citation {  
      height: 1.875rem; 
    } */


/*@media only screen and (max-width: 760px) {
      #quotes-section content {
        padding: 1.875rem .625rem;
      }
    
      #quotes-section quote {
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        line-height: 1.4;
      }
    
      #quotes-section quote-citation {
        display: block;
        padding-top: 1rem;
        margin: auto;
      }
    }
    
    /* Footer */

footer {
  background-color: #9b9b9b;
  padding: 1.5rem 2rem;
}


/*footer .content {
      color: white;
      display: flex;
      font-size: .75rem;
    }
    
    footer .copyright {
      flex-grow: 1;
    }
    
    @media only screen and (min-width: 760px) {
      footer .content {
        font-size: .625rem;
      }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Damion" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./resources/css/reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./resources/css/style.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Header -->
  <header>
    <div class="content">
      <a href="index.html" class="desktop logo">Fotomatic</a>
      <nav class="desktop">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Product detail</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/">Follow us <img class="icon" src="./resources/images/instagram.png"></a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <nav class="mobile">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="./resources/images/ic-logo.svg"></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="./resources/images/ic-product-detail.svg"></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="./resources/images/ic-about-us.svg"></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" class="button">Join us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>

  <!-- Main Content -->
  <div class="main-content">

    <!-- Sign Up Section -->

    <div id="sign-up-section" class="banner">
      <div id="sign-up-cta">
        <div class="content center">
          <div class="header">
            <h2 class="cursive">Instant</h2>
            <h1 class="striking">FORMAT CAMERA</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="email">
            <span>
                      Email us to request a demo and be in our waiting list for the <strong>Febuary 2017</strong> release!
                    </span>
            <div class="button">Join the waiting list</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Features Section -->
    <div id="features-section">
      <div class="feature">
        <div class="center">
          <div class="image-container">
            <img src="./resources/images/feature-1.png" />
          </div>
          <div class="content">
            <h2>Advanced, automatic, instant</h2>
            <h3>Shutter speed, apperture and flash output adjust automatically</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="feature">
        <div class="center">
          <div class="image-container">
            <img src="./resources/images/feature-2.png" />
          </div>
          <div class="content">
            <h2>Beautifully crafted inside-out</h2>
            <h3>From the paint outside to the tiny screw inside, Fotomatic is crafted with love and 20-year of expertise</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Filters Section -->
    <div id="filters-section">
      <div class="content center">
        <h2>Over 20+ filters to choose from</h2>
        <h3>Feed your creativity with 20 different filter designed by our eclectic in-house photographers!</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="images-container">
        <div class="image-container">
          <img src="./resources/images/filter-1.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="image-container">
          <img src="./resources/images/filter-2.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="image-container">
          <img src="./resources/images/filter-3.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="image-container extra">
          <img src="./resources/images/filter-4.png" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="quotes-section">
      <div class="content center">
        <span class="quote">“It’s truly something that could create a brand new photography Renaissance”</span>
        <img class="quote-citation" src="./resources/images/photography-logo.png" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer>
      <div class="content">
        <span class="copyright">© 2016  Fotomatic, All Rights Reserved</span>
        <span class="location">Designed in NYC</span>
      </div>
    </footer>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: the screenshot of the web page]

Comment: Welcome to SO, please could you edit your question and cut the code down to produce a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image can be centered by setting the image container's side margin to auto.

```
  .feature .image-container {
    border: #9dc20b solid 5px;
    width: 90%;
    height: 65%;
/*  Change this */
    margin: 2rem 2rem 2.5rem 2rem;

/* To this
    margin: 2rem auto 2.5rem auto;
 */

}
```

Here's a link that explains better.
[CSS Margin ~ W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp#:%7E:text=The%20auto%20Value,the%20left%20and%20right%20margins.)

Comment: Thank you, that works. Why would justify-content not work here though? I seem to often have issues using justify-content.